# Reversing inner join query

Tags: mysql, join

Alright so I am trying to reverse this INNER JOIN query. I want to select ALL accounts that dont have a field inside the verification table

I tried this way (tried this as an attempt) but failed

```
SELECT users.*,
user_activations.user_id as user_ID
FROM users 
INNER JOIN user_activations ON 
user_activations.user_id = users.ID
WHERE user_activations.user_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Use a LEFT OUTER JOIN instead to get ALL records from `users` and only those from `user_Activiations` that match. Everything else in your query is 100% correct for your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this several ways. Note the use of sql aliases to shorten your code.

**1)** Use `LEFT JOIN` with `IS NULL` condition on `user_activations` PK (or a not null column) which is called an ANTI-JOIN

```
SELECT 
  u.*
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN user_activations ua ON 
  ua.user_id = u.ID
WHERE ua.user_id IS NULL
```

**2)** Use `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT 
  u.*
FROM users u
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM user_activations ua
  WHERE ua.user_id = u.ID
)
```

Note that in the (1) option we are making use of `LEFT JOIN` combined with a `WHERE` condition which is applied to whole joined dataset and effectively removes rows that would match with the `INNER JOIN` (intersection of data from both tables through common column values).

In (2) option we have a contradicted `EXISTS` operator using `NOT` keyword which when found any matching row based on the `WHERE` clause inside a subquery, discards it from the output.

Comment: Thanks bro! Works like a cham

Comment: @TomislavNikolic carry on with your magic! Consider accepting an answer if it helped you.

Comment: Thanks once again and of course I will :) Just gotta wait 1-2 more minutes to do so